# Multilizer

Tags: c++

При установке программы выскакивает "Нарушение доступа по адресу 0069738A в модуле Multilizer.exe . Читайте адреса 00000000". Что это такое и как с этим бороться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это означает, что в программе ошибка. Скорее всего — разыменование нулевого указателя. Больше на основе вашей информации ничего установить нельзя.